# Tiling with exactly 2013 different ways

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

A rectangle with side lengths integers $a$ and $b$ will be covered with tiles, rectangular with a length of one side so that a portion of the rectangular area will be covered with black tiles and the rest will be covered with white tiles. Determine the smallest possible values for a and b such that the tile installation process will be completed with at least $2013$ different ways.

Comment: Is this a question from a contest?  If so, then provide details of the contest and add the [tag:contest-math] tag.

Comment: Actually this is an undergraduate TST of Indonesia at year 2013

Comment: I guess to avoid technicalities you want to have $a$ and $b$ being destinct natural numbers. Your rectangular tiles have one side $a$? What about the other side (maybe unit length?)? Try to see how many different ways of tiling with black and white you get for small values of $b$. Can you see the general pattern?

Comment: No i cant seee anything

Comment: I don't understand if there is some restriction on how the tiles are laid within the area. It sounds like there might be some particular way in which the black tiles are laid - what is that, if anything? Otherwise I guess we're just looking at the total number of tiles, which is not very difficult...

Comment: @Joffan could you please post your solution then?

Comment: As soon as you have 11 tiles, there would be $2^{11}=2048$ options on a free choice of colour per tile. Depending on exactly what "the smallest possible values for a and b" means, you might go for the $3\times 4$ rectangle (rather than $1\times 11$). But I still feel that there is a more complicated setup being hinted at in the jumbled language of the question.

Comment: mmm so which sentence dont you uderstand most???? @Joffan

Comment: "... rectangular with a length of one side so that a portion of the rectangular area ..." - what does "rectangular" refer to? what is "a length of one side" talking about? what does "a portion" mean here?

Comment: Portion mean some of it